# How can I update my reactions when I click any icon

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component I am managing the states using redux and accessing the array data for the component from redux store using a new map. I need to be able to get my icon's value to increment when clicked. I am not sure how to get access to the values of my reactions to make this work and handle my click event with `handleReactions`

constants.js

```
/** @constant */
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    uploads: new Map(),
};

export const USER_UPLOADS = [
    {
        _id: 0,      
        image: 'http://sugarweddings.com/files/styles/width-640/public/1.%20The%20Full%20Ankara%20Ball%20Wedding%20Gown%20@therealrhonkefella.PNG',
        reactions: {
            dislike: 0,
            like: 0,
            maybe: 0,
        },
        story: "It's my birthday next week! What do you think?",
        user: 'Chioma',
    },
    {
        _id: 1,        
        image: 'https://dailymedia.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/7915550_img20181007141132_jpeg01c125e1588ffeee95a6f121c35cd378-1.jpg',
        reactions: {
            dislike: 0,
            like: 0,
            maybe: 0,
        },
        story: 'Going for an event. Do you like my outfit?',
        user: 'Simpcy',
    },
    {
        _id: 2,        
        image: 'https://i0.wp.com/www.od9jastyles.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/ankara-styles-ankara-styles-gown-ankara-tops-ankara-gowns-ankara-styles-pictures-latest-ankara-style-2018-latest-ankara-styles-ankara-ankara-styles.png?fit=437%2C544&ssl=1',
        reactions: {
            dislike: 0,
            like: 0,
            maybe: 0,
        },
        story: 'Saturdays are for weddings. Yay or nay?',
        user: 'Angela',
    },
];
```

actions.js

```
import { UPDATE_REACTION, REQUEST_UPLOAD_LIST } from './actionTypes';

/**
 * Triggers request to react on a post
 *
 * @function
 * @return {Object} The {@link actionTypes.REQUEST_UPLOAD_LIST REQUEST_UPLOAD_LIST}
 * action.
 */
export function updateReaction(itemid, reaction) {
    return {
        itemid,
        reaction,
        type: UPDATE_REACTION,
    };
}

/**
 * Triggers request for the lists of uploads
 *
 * @function
 * @return {Object} The {@link actionTypes.REQUEST_UPLOAD_LIST REQUEST_UPLOAD_LIST}
 * action.
 */
export const requestUploadList = payload => ({
    payload,
    type: REQUEST_UPLOAD_LIST,
});
```

reducers.js

```
import { UPDATE_REACTION, REQUEST_UPLOAD_LIST } from './actionTypes';
import { INITIAL_STATE, USER_UPLOADS } from './constants';

/**
 * Creates a Javascript Map with the user uploads mapped by id
 *
 * @param {Array} USER_UPLOADS - a users uploads
 * @return {Map} - the user uploads
 */

function generateUploadsMap() {
    const setOfUserUploads = new Map();

    USER_UPLOADS.forEach(userUpload => {
        const { _id } = userUpload;

        setOfUserUploads.set(_id, userUpload);
    });

    return setOfUserUploads;
}

function updateItemReactions(itemid, reaction, uploads) {
    const upload = uploads.get(itemid);
    upload.reactions = {
        ...upload.reactions,
        [reaction]: upload.reactions[reaction] + 1,
    };
    uploads.set(itemid, upload);
    return uploads;
}

console.log(updateItemReactions());
export default (state = { ...INITIAL_STATE }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REQUEST_UPLOAD_LIST: {
            return {
                ...state,
                uploads: generateUploadsMap(),
            };
        }
        case UPDATE_REACTION: {
            const { uploads } = state;

            return {
                ...state,
                uploads: updateItemReactions(action.itemid, action.reaction, uploads),
            };
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

home.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { Avatar, Card, Icon, List } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { LIST_TEXTS, STYLES } from '../constants';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import { getUploads } from '../selectors';

const { AVATAR, CARD_CONTAINER, CARD_LIST, ICON, USER_LIST } = STYLES;
const { INNER, MORE, UPLOAD, VERTICAL } = LIST_TEXTS;

const IconText = ({ type, text }) => (
    <span>
        <Icon type={type} style={ICON} />
        {text}
    </span>
);
function createReactionsIcon(item, updateReaction) {
    const { like, dislike, maybe } = item.reactions;
    const icons = [
        { reaction: 'like', text: `${like}`, type: 'heart' },
        { reaction: 'dislike', text: `${dislike}`, type: 'dislike' },
        { reaction: 'maybe', text: `${maybe}`, type: 'meh' },
    ];
    return icons.map(({ reaction, text, type }) => (
        <IconText
          onClick={updateReaction(item._id, reaction)}
          key={reaction}
          type={type}
          text={text}
        />
    ));
}

class Home extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { requestUploadList } = this.props.actions;

        requestUploadList();

    }

        updateReaction = (itemid, reaction) => {
        const { updateReaction } = this.props.actions;
        updateReaction(itemid, reaction);
    }

    render() {
        const { uploads } = this.props;
        const values = Array.from(uploads.values());

        return (
            <div style={CARD_CONTAINER}>
                <List
                  itemLayout={VERTICAL}
                  dataSource={values}
                  renderItem={item => (
                      <List.Item style={USER_LIST}>
                          <Card
                            actions={createReactionsIcon(item, this.updateReaction)}
                            cover={<img alt={UPLOAD} src={item.image} />}
                            extra={<Icon type={MORE} />}
                            hoverable
                            title={(
                                <a href="/">
                                    <Avatar src={item.image} style={AVATAR} />
                                    {item.user}
                                </a>
                            )}
                            type={INNER}
                            style={CARD_LIST}
                          >
                              {item.story}
                          </Card>
                      </List.Item>
                  )}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Home.propTypes = {
    uploads: PropTypes.instanceOf(Map),
    actions: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    uploads: getUploads(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mapDispatchToProps`, you have bound your action creators and set the for the `actions` prop passed down in `Home` component.

The `Icon` element generated in `createReactionsIcon` doesn't know of a way to handle `onClick` event not without giving a way to dispatch an action to the `redux-store` to update reaction for it.

In `Home`, `actions.updateReactions` needs to be forwarded to `createReactionsIcon` and registered for the `onClick` event for its `IconText`.

```
render() {
  //...
  <Card
    actions={createReactionsIcon(item, this.props.actions.updateReaction)}
  //...
}
```

In `createReactionsIcon`,

```
function createReactionsIcon(item, updateReaction) {
  const { like, dislike, maybe } = item.reactions;


  const icons = [
    { reaction: 'like', text: `${like}`, type: 'heart'},
    { reaction: 'dislike', text: `${dislike}`, type: 'dislike'},
    { reaction: 'maybe', text: `${maybe}`, type: 'meh'},
  ];
  //...
  return icons.map(({ reaction, text, type }) => (
    <IconText 
      onClick={() => updateReaction(item._id, reaction)} 
      key={reaction}
      type={type}
      text={text}
    />
  ));
}
```

Here, the definition for `updateReaction` action creator in `actions.js` should be modified to include more fields like items and reaction for the action.

```
function updateReaction(itemid, reaction) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_REACTION,
    itemid,
    reaction
  }
}
```

The reducer for `UPDATE_REACTION` action type is then made to use this for updating the reaction for the item id in `reducer.js`.

```
///...
case UPDATE_REACTION:
  const { uploads } = state;

  return {
    ...state,
      uploads: updateItemReaction(action.itemid, action.reaction, uploads),
    };
  }
///...
```

where `updateItemReaction` is a function defined as:

```
function updateItemReaction(itemid, reaction, uploads) {
  const upload = uploads.get(itemid)
  const uploadUpdate = {
    ...upload,
    reactions: {
      ...upload.reactions,
      [reaction]: upload.reactions[reaction] + 1
    }
  }

  uploads.set(itemid, uploadUpdate)
  return uploads;
}
```

> Now, while the above way is how you go seeing that the object in store is a `Map`.
>   Care must be taken to update only the part of the store that changed so that only components using values from that part of the store are re-rendered.
>
> I strongly recommended considering usage of immutable data structures for your component state or strictly treating the store to be immutable by using plain objects.

Comment: I updated the changes according to your steps. Please check the edited code above. The click event does not render

Comment: Oh, I see why. onClick prop should be set to a function. As is it is invoked immediately and set to the value returned by the dispatch function.

Comment: It says `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` also I suppose this is what you mean `onClick={() => updateReaction(item._id, reaction)}`

Comment: `uploads` is set in `state` as far as I can see and that is destructured from it in the reducer. Maybe `console.log(updateItemReactions());` line is causing that error.

Comment: No problem. Thanks a bunch. Will debug.

Comment: If you find that the reaction count isn't updated, that may be resulting from the fact only the `reactions` part is updated to a new object and so React isn't rendering the IconText with updated value for the reactions. You can fix that by replacing `upload` with a new object that copies its contents and updates `reactions` in it in `updateItemReaction`.